# What are the various techniques for detecting walls in buildings (architectural) in floor plan images?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, thresholding

I have to process building floor plan images to extract walls from the structure. It is trivial in case of binary images; but the images in our case are colored, and have different colored walls. This restricts us from using any thresholding operation as we cannot assume the walls will always be the darkest. How can I come up with an algorithm that can work  on all sorts of images?

Comment: You can't come up with a universal algorithm, 'cause who knows what all the different types of plans will look like. Restrict the problem to the types of plans you know about. Write algorithms that work for most of them and exceptions for those that don't. As for colour, why not segment using both intensity AND colour?

Comment: All Images are NOT different. The thing which is common is all images is that they all have walls, and these compose of major portion of images. What I'm asking is that `Is there an algorithm that exploits this quality of Image?`

Comment: LOL ok. By "all sort of Images" you mean "all THESE sorts of images", that is, plans with colored walls. Sorry. You need a line detector, or perhaps Canny edge detector. Post an example image.

Comment: Edge/line detection won't work.. It'll bring all the additional elements of the Image which have an Edge, but aren't a wall. Then We'll have to classify which ones are from walls.

Comment: Depends what line/edge detector you use and what further processing is applied. For example, limit it to long straight lines. Do you have an example image?

Comment: Could you upload a sample floor plan image? That'll give us a better understanding of your problem

Comment: As @geometrikal and Shravya said you should upload some images as well as provide details on what methods you tried so far.

Comment: @shreelock Please edit your question to include an image, it will allow us to understand more precisely what it is about.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Template matching by taking a small cutout of the wall whose length is long enough so that it is not confused with other elements. Keep the threshold value high(around 0.9 or higher) and then check the bounding boxes predictions.